# Connect google cloud sql to android studio project

Tags: android, android-studio, google-cloud-sql

I'm creating a google cloud mysql and I want to connect the data into my android studio project. After I browser all of the documents from google cloud I still can't figure out how to do it.

The google platform supporter said using google endpoint, can anybody specify the way of connection.

Please help!
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use public ips directly listed in your mysql instances page on
https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances?project=[your-project-name]
You will have to whitelist your IP to do this.

Otherwise you can also try installing proxies, which can help you connect 
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#proxy